# Is there a way to get a list of all placeholders in a cheetah template

Tags: python, cheetah

For example, if I have a template such as

```
"SELECT * FROM myOrders WHERE order_id = ${orderId} and order_date = ${orderDate}"
```

I would like to get a list of all placeholders in that template, i.e. ['orderId', 'orderDate']

Answer (score 1):

I can use a regex to pull those placeholders out.

p.s. Still, it would be nice to have that feature in the Cheetah API, perhaps in the Template class.

example:

```
import re
templateDef = """
SELECT * FROM myOrders WHERE order_id = ${orderId} and order_date = ${orderDate}
"""
placeholders = re.findall(r"\${(\w+)}", templateDef)
print placeholders
```

Answer (score 1):

[Formatter.parse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.parse) should work:

```
s = "SELECT * FROM myOrders WHERE order_id = ${orderId} and order_date = ${orderDate}"

from string import Formatter
#literal_text, field_name, format_spec, conversion
print([plh for _, plh, _,_  in Formatter().parse(s) if plh])
['orderId', 'orderDate']
```

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
vars = set()

class DummyDict:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        vars.add(key)
        return 'X'

str(Template('Hello $A $B $C', searchList=[DummyDict()]))

print(vars)
```

Prints:

> {'B', 'A', 'C'}